# Wordpress Woocommerce Pagination resets filters when moving to page 2+

Tags: wordpress, filter, pagination, facet

Im using wordpress woocommerce website, and on the shop pages, the filters used under [facetwp facet="reset"] are being reset to default 'all' (not filtered) when moving from page 1 to 2 and above.
The website is also not reducing the pagination amount when using the filters, for example selecting a particular colour i.e. 'black' should only show 15 products, effectively 2 pages (12 products per page) however it still shows the option of 1-40 pages.
Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Cassie

i havent tried anything as of yet as i dont want to make anything worse.